# how to use Cell tower triangulation in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, gps

In my app, I dont want to work off of location services. I want to get coordinates using Cell tower triangulation on the iphone.

Please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use API called `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`. From [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html) -

> startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges service offers a significant
>   power savings and provides accuracy that is good enough for most
>   applications. It uses the device’s cellular radio to determine the
>   user’s location and report changes in that location, allowing the
>   system to manage power usage much more aggressively than it could
>   otherwise.

So in code this is how it would look -

```
 self.locationManager     = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
 locationManager.delegate = self;
 [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

Comment: will it run in background for unlimited time?

Comment: it will run till you keep your app open. If you want it to run as background service that too is possible. Also note that this API (like normal location api) is a monitoring service, i.e. you register for it and upon any change in location it will call the delegate. hope that clears it. happy codeing...